# Can I configure Exchange 2013 to allow mailbox access only from specifically authorized systems?

Tags: exchange-2013

We are planing to setup a new office. For this, we have a specific requirement.

We have approximately 50 desktop and 50 laptop users, and we want them to access their Exchange mail on their official laptop and desktop only. Thus we want to **restrict access to their mail accounts to only authorized laptops and desktops;** we don't want them to access their mail accounts using their personal system and mobile.

Is it possible in Exchange 2013 to restict access to accounts to predefined systems in such a way?

Comment: Hi Aditya, and welcome to Super User. I edited your question some for spelling and clarity. Since this is about Exchange server software, I have also voted to migrate it to Server Fault, where you are likely to get better answers. (Super User is for questions relevant to enthusiast computer users; Server Fault is for questions relevant to system administrators.) Should you feel my edit changed your intent in any way, then feel free to [edit] further.

Comment: 1) Don't let personal devices connect to your network.  2) Disable OWA 3) Don't offer a VPN to connect to the network 4) Require 2-factor authentication that mobile devices don't support 5) Create a personnel policy that prohibits it.

Comment: i also want my users to access mail out of office but in authorize device only.  how can i create personal policy that prohibits it.

Comment: You draft a policy for your employees that states they will not access email from anything other than their company-sanctioned laptop.